# Since the example in the documentation is broken, how do I solve a non-linear system of equations numerically in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, solver

The [documentation on `nonlinsolve`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#nonlinsolve) gives this example:

```
from sympy.core.symbol import symbols
from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve
x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z', real=True)
nonlinsolve([x*y - 1, 4*x**2 + y**2 - 5], [x, y])
{(-1, -1), (-1/2, -2), (1/2, 2), (1, 1)}
```

but even in the live shell on their website, that throws an error:

```
>>> from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name nonlinsolve
```

How can I use `nonlinsolve` to solve a system of equations numerically? I know I can use `ufuncify` to convert the equations into a system that `scipy.optimize.fsolve` can solve, but I would rather avoid those couple of lines of boilerplate and just use SymPy directly.

According to the [SymPy documentation on `solve`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html), using `solve` is not recommended. For nonlinear systems of equations, the documentation recommends [`sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve), which is what I'm trying to use here.

Comment: use `sympy.solve([x*y - 1, 4*x**2 + y**2 - 5], [x, y])`

Comment: @Stelios According to the Sympy documentation, [using `solve` is not recommended](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html). I'll add a statement about that to my question.

Comment: The docs are perhaps a bit aggressive about that. solveset is indeed going to replace solve, but there are still instances where it is necessary, such as nonlinear systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this module is not included into `1.0.0` release but is available only in current `head`. Anyway, it may be good idea to check out current state of `sympy` repo as their releases are rather rare.

According to the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/install.html), this is as simple as

```
git clone git://github.com/sympy/sympy.git
cd sympy
sudo python setupegg.py develop
```

(I had to use `python3` instead of `python` as I have both Python 2 and Python 3 system-wide installations. You also possibly can use `virtualenv` to avoid `sudo`.)

After that, latest github version will be available with ordinary `import`.

```
import sympy
print(sympy.__version__)
# 1.0.1.dev
```

Now the example works:

```
from sympy.core.symbol import symbols
from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve
x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z', real=True)
nonlinsolve([x*y - 1, 4*x**2 + y**2 - 5], [x, y])
# {(-1, -1), (-1/2, -2), (1/2, 2), (1, 1)}
```

P.S. If you are really interested in *numeric* solution of your equation, it seems that `ufuncify` + `fsolve` thing will suit you better. SymPy is a computer algebra system, so `nonlinsolve` will do its best to solve nonlinear system *analytically*, not numerically. And of course it can fail (as with any analytic solvers):

```
nonlinsolve([x**5 + x**2 + 1], [x])
# {(CRootOf(x**5 + x**2 + 1, 0),), (CRootOf(x**5 + x**2 + 1, 1),), (CRootOf(x**5 + x**2 + 1, 2),), (CRootOf(x**5 + x**2 + 1, 3),), (CRootOf(x**5 + x**2 + 1, 4),)}
```

Comment: For Windows users, go to https://github.com/sympy/sympy, download the zip, expand it in a convenient new folder, CD inside the folder that contains setup.py and then execute `python setup.py install`. Prepare for a lengthy wait whilst this process bumps and grinds its way to a conclusion. Then check that you can `import sympy` and that `sympy.__version__` is what you expected.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to solve the systems numerically, use `nsolve`. It requires an initial guess for the solution (there are also many options you can pass to use different solvers, see http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve and http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html).

```
In [1]: nsolve([x*y - 1, 4*x**2 + y**2 - 5], [x, y], [1, 1])
Out[1]:
matrix(
[['1.0'],
 ['1.0']])
```

For symbolic solutions, I would recommend using the old `solve`, until `nonlinsolve` matures.